# Get method names and lines from git commit - python

Tags: python, git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am wondering if there is a way to get the list of method names that are modified along with modified lines and file path from git commit or if there are any better solution for python files

I have been going through few answers in stackoverflow where the suggestion was to edit the gitconfig file and .gitattributes but I couldn't get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Git has no notion of the semantics of the files it tracks. It can just give you the lines added or removed from a file or the bytes changed in binary files.

How these maps to your methods is beyond Git's understanding. However there might be tools and/or scripts that will try and heuristically determine which methods are affected by a (range of) commits.